# HTML formatting causing layout issues

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, filezilla

I've come across a strange issue today that I can't say that I've ever come across in the more than five years I've been designing websites.

I'm moving a simple HTML website from one host to another. However, the HTML formatting that I've done to the code doesn't seem to display properly on the new host. One part of the code in particular is this:

```
<header>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
</header>
```

The CSS is:

```
header div {
     width:50%;
     padding:0px;
     margin:0px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     display:inline-block;
}
```

Previously, the two `div`s would display side by side within the `header` element. But now, the two elements are on different lines. But they should fit on the same line. For some reason there is a space added between the two elements, which bumps the second element to a new line.

If I change the HTML code to all one line (removing the whitespace), like:

```
<header><div></div><div></div></header>
```

It displays just fine.

Why is this happening and how to I fix it without having the minify my HTML code? It happens throughout my website on any inline-block elements that take a combined total of 100% of the width. For example, my sidebar is now displaying below my content.

As I already mentioned, it worked fine before on a previous host. I made no changes to the HTML code. Simply logged into Filezilla, copied the files from the old server to my desktop and then logged into the new server and uploaded them to the new server.

Comment: Filezilla's character encoding can cause these issues, changing it to binary solves such mishaps in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download your files from old server while FileZilla's character encoding is set to Binary, then upload them to your new server.